# How to change "Dashboard" text in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

[image: dashboard]

I need to change "Dashboard" text in wordpress admin section. Any idea how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 5):

Okay I've found a solution and it's working fine :)

```
    function my_custom_dashboard_name(){
        if ( $GLOBALS['title'] != 'Dashboard' ){
            return;
        }

        $GLOBALS['title'] =  __( 'Your new Title' ); 
    }

    add_action( 'admin_head', 'my_custom_dashboard_name' );
```

So this is pretty cool huh! `GLOBAL['title']` returns page title and you can easily override that.

Comment: This is a really awesome solution, if it works. No JS needed!

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress give Us possibility to change text by editing translation file.
In my opinion it's cleaner way

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use JavaScript or jQuery via a custom plugin (or your theme's *functions.php*), since these things are hard-coded into the WordPress core. The following targets the Dashboard title itself:

```
(function($) {
    $('#wpbody-content .wrap h2:eq(0)').html('NEW TITLE HERE');
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Yeah! that's hard-coded in index.php file. I was looking for a way to filter or any hook. Seems like I've to do it in your way.